# SSRS Report Parameters Interactive

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a report that requires 3 parameters, all 3 has q query to pre populate them using a dataset for each, so the under their properties the available values is selected with the query.  Default were also set to use the same query. This work fine.

My problem is when the user of the report wanted to enter the values themselves rather than going into the list populated by the query.  Users know the value that they wanted to enter so it's faster for them to enter rather than select. SSRS report seems not to give you the ability to enter if you have set the available values and default values for some reason.  Is their a way to go around this please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one straight forward way to use comma separated multi value parameter rather than list where user enters input.
Below link explains in detail, but I  am quite sure you do not want to stick to below solution.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3479/how-to-use-a-multi-valued-comma-delimited-input-parameter-for-an-ssrs-report/

Another thing you could do is keep your multi value parameter as list as it is and create a text input parameter.

Now if user want to simply choose from list fair enough you will have to handle second parameter as null because user chose from list.

Then on your dataset check and apply filter as 2nd parameter value as not null.

Same goes if user does text input then multi value parameter as not null.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the second option seems to be the viable solution for now, with the extra set of parameters to cater for the entry, but I would have thought that it could be done with the same parameter but cater an entry or selection.  Thank you and much appreciate for the reply.